# Какой язык программирования выбрать для работы с данными? [ Закрыт ]

Tags: python, sql, r

Появилось желание посмотреть в сторону нового языка программирования.
Работаю с данными, использую в основном SQL и R
При выборе нового языка, первым делом посмотрел на Python.
Но, имея в наличии R, не до конца понимаю какие преимущества может дать Python.

Единственное что заинтересовало в Python, это парсинг (как дополнительная возможность получить данные).

Ищу язык который будет дополнением к имеющийся связке SQL + R

На какие языки, вы бы посоветовали посмотреть ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, когда у Вас в руках вся мощь R, то тут трудно что то посоветовать.

По моему, преимущества Python проявятся не как "замена R", а в сиуации, когда Вы на нём будете и писать нечто другое, чем до сих пор.

Как пример - это не "обработка", а "добыча" данных: при помощи какого нибудь BS пропарсить сайт, получить с него данные и записать в mongo или redis. Тут, кстати, прояаится еще и отличие "монговского" ящыка запросов от классчиского SQL.

Опять таки, можно написать что то, что обрабатывает данные нетривиально: WEB - "штука", которая, к примеру, смешивает данные из дух источников: как пример: по номеру телефона получает данные из базы адресов и какой нить социальной сеточки. Или как пример: вы задаёте URL  в VK, а в ответ ВАм сервис выдает "диаграмму частоты использования разных слов в сообщениях этого пользоватея".

В общем, я ВАм привел мнение - что преимущества будут ощутимы только при некоторой, хотя бы небольшой, смене задачи. А дальше - смотрите сами, может оно того и не стОит?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. 
При выборе языка для получения данных я остановился на 2х языках Python, JS. 
Исходя из того что я хотел бы новым языком дополнить имеющуюся связку Python в этом плохо подходит(на мой взгляд), тк обработка данных уже есть в R. Остаётся только парсинг, и автоматизация.
JS на мой взгляд интересней. Mожно не только получать данные, но открывается доступ к вебу (тем более приходилось знакомиться с html \ css) а из минусов данного языка, это обработка данных, которую в R можно компенсировать сполна.
Остановился на JS 
(Оказывается в R так же есть пакет для веб парсинга)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, как по мне, лишен глубоко смысла. Читаем:
"Появилось желание посмотреть в сторону нового языка программирования....Ищу язык который будет дополнением к имеющийся связке SQL + R"

В общем-то не имея информации о том, чем-же вам не угодила указанная связка, кроме желания просто поискать чего нового, рекомендовать вам что-то не представляется возможным.  Дополнение - в каком смысле, для решения каких задач, которые как-то "не так" решаются указанной парой? С таким подходом ответ может быть один -  да берите любой язык, на котором вам будет "не скучно" писать, какая разница.  Ну посоветуют вам взять С++, точно не заскучаете. И что? Не так удобно, и библиотек для обработки данных меньше? Так зато результат очень эффективен в плане использования ресурсов.

В общем я часто говорю, инструмент (язык) надо подбирать под задачу, обратный подход -  всегда от лукавого.

Comment: Я не сказал что данная связка мне не угодна. Как я писал выше, я искал язык который дополнит SQL + R. Вы посоветовали взять C++. Для обработки данных - лучше себя покажет R. А для получения данных (парсинга) есть языки которые с данной задачей спрявятся вразы быстрее. Я выбрал JS.Благодарю за ваш ответ.

Comment: @Akalit на заметку: вопрос недостаточно закрыть, просто написав [Закрыт] в конце названия; нужно также отметить один из ответов, который больше всего помог Вам, либо написать свой ответ (с аргументацией) и также отметить его. Это делается через нажатие на галочку слева от текста вопроса

Comment: @4500zenja, Отметил, Благодарю